# Java 11: package java.net.http does not exist

Tags: java, java-11

Хочу отправить рест-запрос на сервис при помощи HttpClient java 11:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(NOTIFICATION_URL))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .POST(ofString(mapper.writeValueAsString(notification)))
                .build();
        client.sendAsync(request, ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println)
                .join();
```

Но при компиляции получаю ошибку:

> Error:(19, 21) java: package java.net.http does not exist

Команда `java --list-modules` показывает, что такой модуль есть: `java.net.http@11.0.3`. IDE не выделяет мой код как неправильный. Почему эти пакеты не найдены? Использую `openjdk:11-jdk`, собираю проект мавеном.

Comment: Разобрался. В плагинах был настроен уровень языка 10, а нужен 11